# Screenshots taken by Chrome extensions - privacy risk?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'll just get right to the point:
**Is it possible for Chrome extensions to monitor users without them knowing by taking screenshots and/or video?**

There's an extension called [Screencastify](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screencastify-screen-vide/mmeijimgabbpbgpdklnllpncmdofkcpn) that allows you to record your screen. This particular extension (and many others) has a function that allows you to record your entire browser window. And here's the thing. When you set Screencastify to record the entire window, then go into Incognito mode, the browsing you do there gets recorded and saved. When you record the entire window, Chrome will show you a dialog box telling you that "Screencastify wants to share your screen," although it's not to hard to imagine a truly malicious extension bypassing this.

I personally think that this could be a privacy risk, as malicious developers and/or employers could secretly monitor Incognito and normal browsing activity without user knowledge.

Comment: No, this requires explicit consent from the user exactly for this purpose. If you think you found an exploit you can report it on https://crbug.com. Anyway, this question doesn't seem on-topic for StackOverflow and there are other sites in the Stack Exchange network about security whereas SO is about actual development.

Comment: Thanks. I’ll move this there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use other extensions in this case. Find the Screen Capture extension in the Chrome Web Store and install it. It is a simple extension and I think it does not used to monitor your personal information.

You can also try to use the indirect option if you do not want to follow the option of installing an extension. I do not rememebr exactly how it works but you can read the full guide at [rocketfiles.com](https://rocketfiles.com/articles/how-to-screenshot-on-chrome)